# Drawing a Circular arc with a chord of a circle (Line segment) with TikZ, like a Wikipedia picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

this is my first question in this forum.
I want to draw something like a picture from the Wikipedia article about the circle.

This is the picture.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve:

- The circle chord should be in blue. The endpoints of the circle chord (which are on the circle) should be named A and B and shall be written in blue like the chord.
- The circle arc between A and B shall be red.
- The line segments from the midpoint to A and midpoint to B shall be dashed and green.
- Additionally there shall be a short arc which shall picture the angle alpha both in green.
- The circle chord and the circle arc shall be named and the names colored.
- I'm unsure how to specify points A and B. In my attempt, I simply drew a line and then calculated the intersection points with the circle. Maybe there are better programming solutions that are less random.
- And I don't like the solution with \def which is a LaTeX primitive, I don't want to risk and redefine an existing command. Maybe there is an alternative solution for that. I had to do that because it is not possible to use the color{}{} command within the (name intersections ... by)-part.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
    
% PGF/TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows, shapes, trees, intersections}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
       help lines/.style = {very thin, color=gray!50}, 
       dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, radius=2cm}
        ]
    
\def\Ca{\textcolor{blue}{$C$}}
\def\Cb{\textcolor{blue}{$C'$}}
    
\draw[help lines] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
    
\draw[name path=Circle] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\coordinate[label=below:$M$] (M) at (0,0);
\node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=0pt] at (M) {};
    
\path[name path={Sekante1}] (-2.5,-0.5) -- (2.5,2);
    
\path[name intersections={of=Sekante1 and Circle, by={[label=right:\Cb]C2, [label=left:\Ca]C1}}];
    
    
\draw[blue!50, thick] (C1) -- (C2);
\draw[green, dashed] (M) -- (C1);
\draw[green, dashed] (M) -- (C2);
    
\node[dot] at (C1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE!

Comment: Welcome. // +1 for your nice first question, providing all we like to see here : )

Answer (score 7):

The minimum (no labels) like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

% PGF/TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[red,thick] (50:2.5) arc (50:170:2.5) ;
        \draw[thick] (-190:2.5) arc (-190:50:2.5);
        \draw[blue] (50:2.5)--(170:2.5);
        \draw[green,dashed] (0,0)--(50:2.5);
        \draw[green,dashed] (0,0)--(170:2.5);
        \draw[thin] (50:.5) arc (50:170:.5) node[midway, above] () {$\alpha$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT (with some label)**:

[image]

Code (very minimal):

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw,red,thick,name=a] (50:2.5) arc (50:170:2.5) node[midway,above,sloped] () {arco};
        \draw[thick] (-190:2.5) arc (-190:50:2.5);
        \path[draw,blue,thick,name=b] (50:2.5)--(170:2.5) node[midway,sloped,above] () {corda};
        \draw[green,dashed] (0,0)--(50:2.5);
        \draw[green,dashed] (0,0)--(170:2.5);
        \draw[thin] (50:.5) arc (50:170:.5) node[midway, above,sloped] () {$\alpha$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) instead of TikZ, just for comparison.

[image]

You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric a, b;
a = 1.618; b = 4.2;  % arbitrary "points" round the circle - 8 points in all
path C; 
C = fullcircle scaled 180;

draw subpath (a, b) of fullcircle scaled 42 withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;
draw point a of C -- origin -- point b of C dashed evenly withcolor 2/3 green;
draw point a of C -- point b of C withcolor 1/4[blue, white];
draw subpath (a, b) of C withcolor 3/4 red;
draw subpath (b, a+8) of C;

dotlabel.urt("$A$", point a of C);
dotlabel.llft("$B$", point b of C);
label("$\alpha$", 10 unitvector(point 1/2(a+b) of C)); 
label.ulft("\textsf{Kreissehne}", 1/3[point a of C, point b of C]) withcolor 3/4 blue;
label.ulft("\textsf{Kreisbogen}", point a + 1 of C) withcolor 1/2 red;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

#### Notes

- The path `C` is a copy of the built-in `fullcircle` path scaled to 180 pt (63.5 mm).
- The path has eight "points" equally spaced around it starting at 3 o'clock, so that `point 2 of C` is at the top, and `point 6 of C` at the bottom, and so on.
- `subpath (a, b) of C` is the part of `C` from `point a of C` to `point b of C`, moving anti-clockwise, providing `a < b`.  To run anti-clockwise from `b` to `a` you add 8 to `a`.

Comment: Great,when i grow up i need to be like,I have troubles using METAPOST

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `angle`, `arrows.meta` and `quotes` libraries. Sizes of radius and angles are (so far) hard coded, but can be simple replaced by defining `\pgfmathsetmacro` for them.

**Edit:**
If you use `babel` package for support some other languages as are German, Spanish, my native languages, than English, they redefine meaning of some letters used in programing `tikz`. For such a case is defined `tikz` library `babel`, which in the most of cases resolve this issues. Now added to MWE below:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % <--- added

% PGF/TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                quotes,
                babel        % <--- added
                }
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
              > = Straight Barb,
ang/.style = {draw, <->,
              angle eccentricity=0.5},
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
help lines/.style = {very thin, color=gray!50},
                        ]
\draw[help lines] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
% drawing red arc
\draw[thick, red]   ( 60:2) arc (60: 180:2cm);
% drawing black arc
\draw[thick]        ( 60:2) arc (60:-180:2cm);
% drawing  secant with labels at the end
\draw[thick,blue]   ( 60:2) coordinate[label=above right:$C'$] (c') --
                    (180:2) coordinate[label=left:$C$] (c);
% center of circle
\node[dot, label=below:$M$] (m) {};
% mark angle
\draw[densely dashed]   (c) -- (m) -- (c');
%  descriptions
\draw[<-] (120:2)-- ++(150:1)  node[left] {Kreisbogen};
\draw[<-] (130:1.5) -- ++ (150:1) node[left] {Kreissehne};
% mark angle
\pic [ang, "$\alpha$"]     {angle = c'--m--c};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have noticed that some piece of code of your example gets in conflict with the babel package and ngerman option. This particuar line produces a conflict: < \pic [ang, "$\alpha$"]     {angle = c'--m--c}; > Why does this happen? And how to solve this with using the babel[ngerman] package.

Comment: @Texfriend23, if adding library `babel` resolve your problem. See edited answer.

Comment: Yes, `babel` resolves the problem. For more details see the TikZ manual and the section about `Babel` library . There it is explained that Babel makes certain punctuation marks like `"` to active characters, which then leads to conflicts with the Tikz code, especially when using the `quotes` library and the charakter `"` (quotation marks). Just use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` . `babel` library is specially made for this type of conflict.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the longer code can be easier to understand and to modify. So here we go: just an other way to do it. Basic idea:

- **define** coordinates first, as this problem allows to do it
- use A, B and M to draw all relevant geometries
- finally place labels etc.
- use polar coordinates almost always

The code below followed this route, and applied just some gentle refactoring to remove duplicates in code. It turned out that using `green` would have little contrast, so I replaced it by `green!50!black!100`; perceive `!50` and `!100` as sliders when mixing green and black.

Some alternatives:

- you could replace absolute positions, e.g. for the labels, by relative ones
- you could predefine label coordinates, like `\coordinate (LB) at ( 95:2.8);` and later put a node there: `\node[brown] (KB) {Kreisbogen};`
- you could define and use different arrow-symbols for the pointers and the angles arc
- you could introduce some `\def` statements to further predefine the various coordinates and the relationship amongst them: following the paradigm *change all in one place only* makes adjustments very flexible
- etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}% to draw angle and use greek letters
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% to change the arrow symbol

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        grn/.style=green!50!black!100,% a stronger green
        > = {Stealth}% replacing all standard arrow symbols
    ]
    % ~~~ set coordinates ~~~
    \coordinate (M) at (0,0);   % center
    \coordinate (A) at (170:2); % A
    \coordinate (B) at ( 70:2); % B
        
    % ~~~ arcs ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[red]  (B) arc (70:170:2);
    \draw       (B) arc (70:-190:2);% negative, to reverse drawing direction
    
    % ~~~ chords ~~~~~~~
    \draw[blue]         (B) -- (A);
    \draw[grn,dashed]   (B) -- (M) -- (A);
    
    % ~~~ marking the angle ~~~
    \pic["$\alpha$",draw,<->,grn] {angle = B--M--A};% see ch. 41
    
    % ~~~ labels (one way to do it) ~~~
    \node[blue,xshift=-3mm]             at (A) {A};
    \node[blue,xshift=2mm, yshift=2mm]  at (B) {B};
    
    \node[brown] (KB) at (95:2.8) {Kreisbogen};
    \node[brown] (KS) at (140:2.8) {Kreissehne};
    \draw[->] (KB) -- (95:2.1);
    \draw[->] (KS) -- (140:1.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have noticed that some piece of code of your example gets in conflict with the babel package and ngerman option. This particuar line produces a conflict: `  \pic["$\alpha$",draw,<->,grn] {angle = B--M--A}; ` Why does this happen? And how to solve this with using the babel[ngerman] package.

Comment: Packages do have side effects every now and then. For this  drawing no language package is needed, strictly speaking: so leave it out. // Unfortunately I have no idea what kind of conflict you encounter. Please consider posting a new question, where you reference to my code and describe your observation in more detail.

Comment: BTW, @Zarko gave an excellent answer in his EDIT to the language question in his answer. So I suggest NOT to raise another question, as it will have been answered many times already (leading to a close), UNLESS you encounter a problem unknown to this community so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzcoor(0,0)(M){$M$}[-90] % center

%% defining A and B: using intersections
\tzline[draw=none]"Sekante1"(-2.5,-0.5)(2.5,2)
\tzcircle[draw=none]"Circle"(M)(2cm)
\tzXpoint{Circle}{Sekante1}(A){$A$}[45]
\tzXpoint{Circle}{Sekante1}(B)[2]{$B$}[180]

%%% alternative way of defining A and B: simple
%\tzcoors(60:2cm)(A){$A$}[45](170:2cm)(B){$B$}[180];

%% arcs
\tzpointangle(M)(A){\angA}
\tzpointangle(M)(B){\angB}
\tzarc'[thick](M)(\angB:\angA:2cm)
\tzarc[thick,red](M)(\angA:\angB:2cm){Kreisbogen}[pos=.3,a]
%% chord
\tzline[thick,blue](A){Kreissehne}[sloped,a](B)
%% dashed lines
\tzline[green,dashed](M)(A)
\tzline[green,dashed](M)(B)
%% dots
\tzdots*(M)(A)(B);
%% angle mark
\tzanglemark[green](A)(M)(B){$\alpha$}[pos=.6]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```